# nuxt js, laravel, token is not provided

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

i'm a learning nuxt js and laravel, I have been doing an api with laravel and the front with nuxt js, when i work on localhost everything works fine but when i upload my api to a remote server the error appears on my nuxt app {"error":"Token is no provided"} this only happens when the api is on the remote server

my nuxt config looks like this

[image]

everything works fine on localhost, but not on the remote server, and on the internet I hardly find any information about it, thanks

in my laravel authController i have this

[image]

Comment: Never used nuxt, but does the fact your config object contain a property called local, with all your values defined, mean those values are only for local. ie) tokenRequired + tokenType. My hunch is this is your problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please Remove images and update your question to have actual code in it. Also visit https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked the developers tool for once? You might find something in the console.  Moreover, try looking the network tab, just make sure that the URL you are hitting is correct and see if you are receiving any kind of response from the remote server.